# I cannot use selenium for 10 concurrent users

Tags: selenium, testing, jmeter, load-testing

Can I test a login Authenticated web application in selenium Automation and Jmeter for 10 users same time usage of the web application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can test it with multiple users

**Bear in mind**, the Webdriver (Selenium) executions are **resource intensive** and require a larger foot print than the normal web http calls.

If you got no other options, than the Selenium Webdriver - It is recommended to use the Webdriver samplers in **Headless mode**.

Also, It is advised to have an **eye on the CPU and memory consumption** of the LGs where the JMeter is running.

Spin up more number of LGs when you are breaching more than **85% of CPU**

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), see [Mixing Selenium Into Your Load Scenario](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) article for details.

However aware that:

1. It's in general [not recommended](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/) mainly because you won't have all the relevant metrics and KPIs
2. Browsers are very resource intensive and each instance [requires 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/99.0/system-requirements/) so you will need 21 GB of RAM to launch 10 browser instances while with JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you can mimic thousands of users with the same hardware

So it's better to use 1 thread for client-side performance testing (i.e. rendering speed) and remaining 9 to use HTTP Request samplers